# Concatenate ordered vectors

Tags: r

How can I concatenate two ordered vectors when

1. they have the same factors and ordering, or
2. they have non-overlapping factors?

Here are two approaches to (1) that don't work (the first returns an integer vector and the second a factor vector):

```r
o1 <- ordered(c('a', 'b'), levels = c('c', 'b', 'a'))
o2 <- ordered(c('c'),      levels = c('c', 'b', 'a'))

c(o1, o2)
#> [1] 3 2 1

unlist(list(o1, o2))
#> [1] a b c
#> Levels: c b a
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When they have the same factors and ordering,

   ```r
   ordered(c(o1, o2), levels = 1:nlevels(o1), labels = levels(o1))
   #> [1] a b c
   #> Levels: c < b < a
   ```
2. When they have non-overlapping factors it's best to explicitly define what you want the new order to be:

   ```r
   p1 <- ordered(c('a', 'b'), levels = c('b', 'a'))
   p2 <- ordered(c('c'))

   new_order <- as.list(c(levels(p2), levels(p1)))
   names(new_order) = new_order
   levels(p1) <- new_order
   levels(p2) <- new_order

   ordered(c(p1, p2), levels = 1:length(new_order), labels = new_order)
   #> [1] a b c
   #> Levels: c < b < a
   ```

   Alternatively, if you like coding dangerously, you can let `rbind` work its dark magic:

   ```
   d = rbind(data.frame(a = p1), data.frame(a = p2))
   d$a
   #> [1] a b c
   #> Levels: b < a < c
   ```

   (note that you lose some control over the factor ordering).